# Boolean Algebra Simplification of $(A + B + C') \cdot(A'\cdot B' + C)$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Good Afternoon all,

I am having trouble simplifying the expression $(A + B + C') \cdot(A'\cdot B' + C)$, I've tried converting $A'\cdot B'+ C$ to $( A' + B' + C)$ and factoring it with the other term but I don't think this is right.

Could anyone solve this step by step, maybe with which rule applied, so I can see how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you maybe clarify what $A,B,C$ are? Since you are tagging your question with boolean-algebra but you used unusual signs for this branch such as $+$ it is not clear what exactly you are talking about. Just add these details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation we have:
$$\begin{align} (A+B+C')\cdot(A'\cdot B'+C) & = A\cdot (A'\cdot B'+C) +B\cdot (A'\cdot B'+C)+C'\cdot (A'\cdot B'+C) \\
& =(A A' B'+ A C) + (B A' B'+ B C)+(C' A' B'+C' C) \\ 
& =0 +A\cdot C+0+B\cdot C+A'\cdot B'\cdot C'+0 \\
& =(A+B)\cdot C+(A+B)'\cdot C' \\ 
& =(A+B)\odot C \end{align}$$
where $\odot$ is the Exclusive NOR.

The laws used in each line are respectively distributive, distributive, complement, distributive and de Morgan, and finally definition of Exclusive NOR.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you posting the rules this really helped!